# Using CDI (Context & Dependency Injection) backing beans instead of Managed Beans

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cdi

I rode that is recommended to use CDI beans as backing beans instead of JSF managed beans.

So i decided to create a little example, to understand how it works, for a **@RequestScopedBean**:

-instead of using **@ManagedBean("beanName")** ,i use **@Named("beanName")**

-instead of using **javax.faces.bean.RequestScopped** i use **javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;**

The demo program is very simple, i have a field and a submit button, when the user inputs something and the page is refreshed, the inputed value is not displayed anymore(It last while the request lasts right?). I think i did everything ok, but i get an exception that says:

> WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces
>   Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service()
>   for servlet Faces Servlet threw
>   exception
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:
>   /index.xhtml @19,47
>   value="#{cdiBean.passedValue}": Target
>   Unreachable, identifier 'cdiBean'
>   resolved to null

This is how my program looks like:

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
        <title>RequestScope demo CDI(Component Dependency Injection)</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form>

    <h3>RequestScope demo CDI(Component Dependency Injection)</h3>

    <h:inputText value="#{cdiBean.passedValue}"/>
    <br/>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="index"/>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**DemoBB.java**

```
package backingbeans;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("cdiBean")//The Named anotation indicates that this is a CDI bean
@RequestScoped//If we use CDI beans the @RequestScoped annotation must come from: javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
public class DemoBB {

    //This value will be saved on the session only until the server responds to the request
    private String passedValue;

    public String getPassedValue() {
        return passedValue;
    }

    public void setPassedValue(String passedValue) {
        this.passedValue = passedValue;
    }   
}
```

-Where is my mistake?

-What is the advantage of using this approach? I still don't understand that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an empty `beans.xml` along with your `web.xml`? I think it is mandatory to be there.

Read section 15.6 [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html_single/#d0e4633). Quote from it:

> CDI doesn't define any special
>   deployment archive. You can package
>   beans in JARs, EJB-JARs or WARs—any
>   deployment location in the application
>   classpath. However, the archive must
>   be a "bean archive". That means each
>   archive that contains beans must
>   include a file named beans.xml in the
>   META-INF directory of the classpath or
>   WEB-INF directory of the web root (for
>   WAR archives). The file may be empty.
>   Beans deployed in archives that do not
>   have a beans.xml file will not be
>   available for use in the application.
>
> In an embeddable EJB container, beans
>   may be deployed in any location in
>   which EJBs may be deployed. Again,
>   each location must contain a beans.xml
>   file.

Comment: Yes that was it i needed to add the beans.xml You are right (+1) I see the application works, but not as i spected, i dont understand why the values from the fields don't disapear after redirection.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answers. Sorry about the vote down before.